# Best Practice merging files after Spark batch job

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hive, impala

we have multiple spark jobs running which connect to different datasources(kafka,oracle, mysql..) and offload/import data via a spark batch.

The job reads the source adds a couple of information and then adds the information to an partitioned (YYYY-MM-DD) hive-parquet table (df...saveAsTable(....)).
The jobs are running every 5 minutes.
Everything is running pretty smooth so far.

"Problem" is now that we found out that it is a big performance increase if we merge the small files inside of the daily partitions.

For now we just use "insert overwrite table" to overwrite the partition with the same data, through that process the data is merged into bigger files.
But the process is manually and feels not really like "BestPractice".

How do you guys deal with that? Must be a very common Issue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can coalesce using Spark. It's an  HDFS best practice, not necessarily Spark

Comment: i know that i can use --getmerge command via hdfs to merge the files in a specific folder and recieve one big file for it.
But to use it that way, I need to implement a process which merges all the files seperate for all partitions remove the original files and move the merged one.

Sounds even more like a workarround to me.

Comment: That merges locally, not back into HDFS. People commonly use NiFi's `MergeContent` processor to compact files into larger ones.

Comment: ok i know nifi is an option as well, but we are running on clouodera and i can believe that there is no other solution for it.

There are millions of usecases for streaming , short intervall offloading and so on which all end in the issue many small files which affects the performance.

Comment: Nifi is just a Java process. You don't require Clouderas permission or tools to install it. You can stand up an entirely separate cluster dedicated to NiFi, or use Spark coalesce functions, as pointed out

Comment: Streamsets is a competing product to NiFi. https://www.cloudera.com/partners/solutions/streamsets.html

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding it correctly, you generate the perquet file's with partitions as below.

```
/user/hive/warehouse/table/date=2015-01-01/nameloadfile1/file.parq
/user/hive/warehouse/table/date=2015-01-01/nameloadfile1/file2.parq
/user/hive/warehouse/table/date=2015-01-01/nameloadfile1/file3.parq
/user/hive/warehouse/table/date=2015-01-01/nameloadfile1/file4.parq
```

Now, you manually merge those file manually. Instead of that you could do like following which can be done automatically.

```
df.coalesce(1).write.mode(SaveMode.Overwrite).partitionBy(<partitioncolumn>).perquet(<HIVEtbl>)
```

The following properties could also come handy. Take a look for these.

```
spark.sql("SET hive.merge.sparkfiles = true")  
spark.sql("SET hive.merge.mapredfiles = true")
spark.sql("SET hive.merge.mapfiles = true")
spark.sql("set hive.merge.smallfiles.avgsize = 128000000")
spark.sql("set hive.merge.size.per.task = 128000000")
```

Hope, this helps.

Comment: thanks ill give it a try. But if im right the hive options your are mentioning are only merging the data/files which are written during the single batch. which means that if i run the job every minute with 1mb, I will have a 1mb file for each batch. 
The coalesce means that i reduce the number of processes writing. I need to check how this affects the parallelizm because i read a jdbc/mysql into that dataframe.

Comment: Again thx for your answer but it does not work in my case. Of course df.coalesce(1).write.... creates an single file, but i load the df from a jdbc connection in front with like 100 mappers each run. This ends in 100 files per batch which is correct for one run. But when the job is executed every 5 min i write like 1200 files per hour where each file is <5 mb. Right now i reduced the parallelization and implemented a subjob which overwrites the day before partition at the next day. The hive options do not change anything.

Comment: repartition(1) is better than coalesce at it allows more parallelism to take place https://reports.telemetry.mozilla.org/post/projects/avoid_coalesce.kp